# Stripe 'create charges' script doesn't run

Tags: forms, stripe-payments, payment

I'm trying to set up stripe payments, but the [create charges](https://stripe.com/docs/charges) script isn't finishing. Here's the script:

```
if ( $_POST && $_POST["amount"] ) {
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    $total = $_POST['amount'];
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
        'amount' => $total,
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'description' => 'Classified Purchase',
        'source' => $token,
    ]);
}
```

What the code does is make sure the user is coming from having successfully submitted this form

```
        <form action="confirmation" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">
          <script
            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
            class="stripe-button btn"
            data-key="pk_test_pWVTgPv7RI4rRSyWVT6g0Zrx"
            data-amount="<?php echo $total * 100; ?>"
            data-name="It's Classified"
            data-description="New Classified Submission"
            data-image="<?php echo $stripe_image; ?>"
            data-locale="auto"
            data-billing-address="true"
            data-email="true"
            data-allow-remember-me="true">
          </script>
        </form>
```

(I added a hidden input to collect the amount due.) And creates a charge of the given amount. The last line to be iterated is

`if ( $_POST && $_POST["amount"] ) {`

after that nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); error_reporting(E_ALL); to your script. Are any errors thrown? I'd also recommend adding an action property to your <form> tag with the location of your script, e.g. `action="charge.php"`

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't tell this from the question, but the mistake is in the API key. It's using the public key, when it should be using the secret key.

Hope that's helpful for anyone struggling with stripe payments in the future!